# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable (Django/Python)

Tags: python, django, fullcalendar

I am attempting to build a REST-type JSON API for my app, and while I'm testing it, I keep getting a cryptic error when I hit the URL of my page.

**URLconf:**

```
url(r'^calendar/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<year>\d+)/(?P<month>\d+)/$', 'calendar_resource'),
```

**views.py:**

```
def json_view(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), mimetype="text/json")
    return wrapper    

@json_view
def calendar_resource(request, id, month, year):
    if id != request.user.id:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    thisMonthEnd = datetime.datetime(year, month, calendar.mdays[month])
    thisMonthStart = datetime.datetime(year, month, 1)
    l = Lesson.objects.filter(student__teacher = request.user).filter(startDate__lte=thisMonthEnd).filter(endDate__gte=thisMonthSta‌​rt)
    lessonList = list(l)
    return lessonList
```

I'm converting the QuerySet result to a list so I can do more operations on it (i.e. insert records that wouldn't be returned in the query) before passing the list back as JSON for processing by fullCalendar.

ETA: This is the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732452/django-ease-of-building-a-restful-interface) that led me to use this implementation.

**Traceback:**

```
Environment:
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:5678/calendar/1/2012/5/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'lessons',
 'registration']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /calendar/1/2012/5/
Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: can you add the error you are getting?

Comment: Request Method: GET

Request URL: http://alpha:5678/calendar/1/2012/5/

Django Version: 1.3.1

Exception Type: TypeError

Exception Value: 
'str' object is not callable

Comment: In your URLConf, it should be `'views.calender_resource'` (and possibly prefixed with the app name), instead of just `'calender_resource'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your URLConf, it should be `'views.calender_resource'` instead of just `'calender_resource'`.

Essentially,

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^calendar/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<year>\d+)/(?P<month>\d+)/$', 'APP_NAME.views.calendar_resource'),
)
```

Or:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('APP_NAME.views',

    url(r'^calendar/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<year>\d+)/(?P<month>\d+)/$', 'calendar_resource'),
)
```

where APP_NAME is the name of the app this view belongs to.

---

For [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#url):

```
url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None, prefix='')
```

> You can use the url() function, instead of a tuple, as an argument to patterns(). This is convenient if you want to specify a name without the optional extra arguments dictionary. For example:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^index/$', index_view, name="main-view"),
    ...
)
```

> This function takes five arguments, most of which are optional:

```
url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None, prefix='')
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide full traceback?

Issues so far:

1. You cannot `json.dumps` on list of model instances directly. If you want such dump, have a look at `django.core.serializers`

   ```
   from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer
   Serializer().serialize(Lesson.objects.filter(...))
   ```
2. `'application/json'` is standard mime-type for json instead of `'text/json'`

Comment: Thanks, I added more information, including full traceback and link to original SO question that influenced me to try this particular implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [field lookup syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#id4). You need to be passing kwargs to `filter()`. This means using `__lt` type syntax instead of the standard python comparison operators.

```
l = Lesson.objects.filter(student__teacher=request.user).filter(startDate__lte= thisMonth).filter(endDate__gte=thisMonthStart)
```

Comment: Good catch. Changed my filter to `Lesson.objects.filter(student__teacher = request.user).filter(startDate__lte=thisMonthEnd).filter(endDate__gte=thisMonthStart)` but still no luck. Same error.