# Django Registration 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-registration, django-settings

I am using Django-registration-email in my Django project. In there documentation ([Django-Registration-Email](https://github.com/bitmazk/django-registration-email)), I am instructed to add **REGISTRATION_EMAIL_REGISTER_SUCCESS_URL** in the **settings.py**. However, this is causing the type error:

```
'str' object is not callable
```

In the settings.py, I set the redirect url as such:

```
REGISTRATION_EMAIL_REGISTER_SUCCESS_URL = '/accounts/register/complete/'
```

And the the url is copied as such:

```
url(
    r'^accounts/register/$',
    RegistrationView.as_view(
        template_name='registration/registration_form.html',
        form_class=CustomEmailRegistrationForm,
        get_success_url=getattr(
            settings,'REGISTRATION_EMAIL_REGISTER_SUCCESS_URL',
            lambda request, user:'/'),
    ),
    name='registration_register',
),
```

And the debug information told me that the first error comes from **/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/views.py in form_valid**

The indicated error line is

```
success_url = self.get_success_url(request, new_user)
```

The whole block is

```
def form_valid(self, request, form):
    new_user = self.register(request, **form.cleaned_data)
    success_url = self.get_success_url(request, new_user)

    # success_url may be a simple string, or a tuple providing the
    # full argument set for redirect(). Attempting to unpack it
    # tells us which one it is.
    try:
        to, args, kwargs = success_url
        return redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)
    except ValueError:
        return redirect(success_url)
```

The traceback is:

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/registration/views.py" in dispatch
  79.         return super(RegistrationView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/registration/views.py" in post
  35.             return self.form_valid(request, form)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/registration/views.py" in form_valid
  83.         success_url = self.get_success_url(request, new_user)

Exception Type: TypeError at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? Thanks a lot! I am stuck by this problem for one whole day!

Comment: Can you post the complete Traceback?

Comment: could it be related to this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809240/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-django-python?rq=1

Comment: I have added the traceback and also the setting of redirect url.

Comment: Hi Faboolous, thank you. I have seen this post and I think it's the problem of url. Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

OK, when you use

```
get_success_url=getattr(
        settings,'REGISTRATION_EMAIL_REGISTER_SUCCESS_URL',
        lambda request, user:'/'),
)
```

in your url handler, you are setting `get_success_url` as a string.  You are then calling it in `form_valid`, as a function, trying to pass it variables.

Comment: Hi GAEfan, thanks for your answer. Actually I copy this block of code from the documentation of Django-registration-email (link: https://github.com/bitmazk/django-registration-email). I think they are trying to pass the redirect url to the backend view. Do you know how to fix it? Thanks a lot, your answer is very helpful!

Comment: You are mixing 2 different packages: django-registration and django-registration-email, and their url handlers are different.  If you put `REGISTRATION_EMAIL_REGISTER_SUCCESS_URL = '/accounts/register/complete/'` in your `settings.py`, then `get_success_url` will always return it as a string.  You need to choose one package or the other, and use it exclusively.

Comment: django-registration-email is a package based on django-registration, so i need to include both in my installed_apps in settings.py, as instructed by the documentation. Do you know what is the "getattr(settings,'REGISTRATION_EMAIL_REGISTER_SUCCESS_URL',lambda request, user:'/')" doing? why using lambda? I kind of regret using django-registration-email

Comment: If you read the `Important` section in django-registration-email, they tell you: "This app has been discontinued due to the give-up of django-registration. Also there are a lot of well developed and more extensive alternatives on the market.

Why don't you check out django-allauth: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth

Comment: Hi GAEfan. Thanks fr your help! You are right, I should move to django-allauth. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find where is the problem: ***REGISTRATION_EMAIL_REGISTER_SUCCESS_URL is expecting a function rather than a string***

So, I should add an one-line function in the settings.py

```
REGISTRATION_EMAIL_REGISTER_SUCCESS_URL = lambda request, user: '/activate/complete/'
```

Anyway, I still would like to move to allauth since django-registration-email is no longer maintained.